# SSIS: add non-existent column to a CSV source

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, multiple-columns

I am loading a large set (10s of thousands) of CSV files into a single staging sql server table, using standard SSIS approach.

Vast majority of source CSV files have identical column structure (order, set of columns, data types). There's around 140 columns all together.

However, in certain (<1%) cases a source file will be lacking some columns (I know exactly which columns they are, and there are three possible combinations of missing columns). This is by design i.e. this is a valid business scenario (meh).

Can I somehow create a "virtual" column (filled with NULL/empty/blank values) for a source CSV connection if (and only if) that column does not exist in the physical source CSV file?

I know I can read CSV header with a C# scripting component and create multiple source connections, and re-direct to the right data flow based on existence (or lack) of certain columns but I am hoping for a more "elegant" solution, with just single CSV data source "smart" enough to "artificially" add blank columns that are missing in the source file.

For simplicity let's assume that the full column set is:

```
ID;C1;C2;C3
```

And that C3 is missing occasionally i.e. some CSV files are:

```
ID;C1;C2
```

Any hints welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no "smart" CSV data source built in to SSIS.

You are certainly going to need to use a script component, but instead of using a Script Task outside the dataflow that directs the control flow to the correct dataflow, you can simply create one dataflow that has a script component as the data source.   The script component reads the CSV that is currently being imported, and if the column in question is missing, it supplies it with NULL or default values.

Comment: Seems legit although I have never created a script component as a data source. There's always the first time - I will give it a try. Thank you.